# How does one correctly create and access a KeyStore in java to store an encryption key?

Tags: java, exception, keystore

I've been mixing and matching code, trying to learn by example for using KeyStores.

I have this createKeyStore method:

```
private static KeyStore createKeyStore(String fileName, String pw) throws Exception
    {
        File file = new File(fileName);

        final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
        if (file.exists())
        {
            // .keystore file already exists => load it
            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(file), pw.toCharArray());
        }
        else
        {
            // .keystore file not created yet => create it
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(fileName), pw.toCharArray());
        }

        return keyStore;
    }`
```

It seems to work, no errors are thrown.

I am then trying to access the code by:

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keystore.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePath), pass.toCharArray());

    String alias = "alias";
    char[] password = pass.toCharArray();

    Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
    keystore.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);

    // Save the new keystore contents
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(keystoreFile);
    keystore.store(out, password);
    out.close();
```

But my call to keystore.load throws an Invalid Keystore Format exception.
I tried to replace the FileInputStream with null, but it seems to throw an error setting the certificate.

TL;DR: I am only trying to store a few encryption keys in this keystore, but I can't seem to access it correctly.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
```

and

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
```

Change these so they agree.

This:

```
Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
keystore.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);
```

is pointless. If there wasn't such a certificate in the keystore, it will fail, and if there was, it will just replace it with itself. What's the point exactly?

> I tried to replace the FileInputStream with null

I cannot imagine why. There's nothing in the Javadoc that suggests that will work.

Comment: That changed something for sure. In the create keystore method, the call to keystore.load now throws and EOFException.

Comment: You aren't closing the `FileOutputStream` after you create the keystore in the first piece of code.

Comment: I am not 100% sure now. I removed the Certificate lines, and I tried to declare a FileINputStream instead of original way so that I could close it. But it still throws the EOFException.

Comment: Works for me. You'll have to show us your current code. Edit it into your question. And the stack trace.

Comment: Strange. Ill erase what I have and all it created and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: That fixed. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation it says to create an empty keystore call the load() method with null as the file input parameter but not the password parameter. Passing null as the password parameter in your else clause causes null pointer exceptions when loading the keystore from file later.

```
keystore.load(null, pass.toCharArray());
```