# Can not serialize AndroidKeyStore to OutputStream

Tags: java, android, serialization, keystore

I'm trying to save an Android `KeyStore` object into a file in order to use the generated private key later. I need to do this because once the app is exited, the private key is erased. To do this, I'm writing a `KeyStore` object into an output stream as per [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-cryptography/keystore.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641454/how-does-one-correctly-create-and-access-a-keystore-in-java-to-store-an-encrypti?rq=1)
example. However, when I attempt to do so, I get the following error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can not serialize AndroidKeyStore to OutputStream

It occurs at `mKeyStore.store(keyStoreOutputStream, keyStorePassword);`

```
mKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
mSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
mKeyStore.load(null);

// Generate private key
PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) mKeyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);
Certificate [] cert = mKeyStore.getCertificateChain(KEY_NAME);
char[] keyStorePassword = null;

// Store private key into mKeyStore
mKeyStore.setKeyEntry(KEY_NAME, key, null, cert);

// Save mKeyStore to outputstream
String filepath = activity.getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/keystore.ks";
try (FileOutputStream keyStoreOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filepath)) {
    mKeyStore.store(keyStoreOutputStream, keyStorePassword);
}

mSignature.initSign(key);
```

Is this the best way to store my `KeyStore` object for later use? If so, how can I go about fixing the `Can not serialize AndroidKeyStore to OutputStream` error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android `KeyStore` is not the same  as `AndroidKeyStore`.

`AndroidKeyStore` is an Android component that can be used to securely generate and store your keys. See 
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore

> The Android Keystore system lets you store cryptographic keys in a container to make it more difficult to extract from the device. Once keys are in the keystore, they can be used for cryptographic operations with the key material remaining non-exportable.

The keys are persistent. Any key generarated into `AndroidKeyStore` will be present after application restart. This is the recommended way to store your keys

Note that the keys are non-extractable. If you need to export the private key in some way, you will need to use an standard keystore file, not AndroidKeystore

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks for your answer!